# How to catch a res.send(404) in ExpressJS production

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just want to confirm that it's indeed not possible to have middleware handle things lik 404,500 when they are return thus:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  res.send(404);
}
```

Ideally I would like, in production, to show a nice missing page but my error handler middleware never gets called if I do it this way no matter the order of things in my configuration (i.e. before, after app router);

Been trying to cleanup my error handling and after a lot of googling it appears that I must create an error object with a Not Found message at which point my middleware can deal with it. Such as https://github.com/robrighter/node-boilerplate/blob/master/templates/app/server.js

Correct?

Comment: Just add the 404 route as a catch all route after the static route and all the routes you've specified, and it will catch all url's that doesn't have a matching static file or route, and you can send a 404 page instead, and you would do that by using something like `res.status(404).send('<p>This is where my super 404 page goes</p>');`

Comment: Catching the 404 as a last route is not an issue - basically in many  database calls when an item is not found I just want to send a 404 - so technically I have a route match but want to send 404 or 401 and so on

Comment: Then you use the next() function to move along to the next matching route, and that is probably the last catch-all 404 route.

Comment: Might as well throw an error due to the amount of typing - I can't use res.send if I use next() and print a page since headers are sent. I can use res.status(404);next() and check for status code in middleware but that's just lame. I guess I would need to extend the response object to have it do something on http codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - There is an finish event being emitted that middleware can use but the response has terminated by then so only useful for logging. So I guess the answer is that it's not possible to do so - it's either do a `res.status(401); throw new Error('No entry!')` type of things or extending Errors such as https://github.com/machadogj/node-simple-errors

```
// "Catch" all status code 
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.on('finish', function() {
    // Do whatever based on status code
    console.log(res.statusCode);
  });
  next();
});

app.use(app.router);

app.get('/missing', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(404);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your routes do something like :

```
exports.index = function(req, res, next) {
    contact_db(function(result) {
        if (result) {
            res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
        }else{
            next();
        }
    });
}

exports.error = function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).send('Not Found !!!');
}
```

and where you define them, do something like

```
app.use(express.static());

app.get('/index', routes.index);

app.get('*', routes.error);
```

simplified to make a point, you'll have to adapt to however you're setting up your routes etc.

Comment: Same issue I commented on above - In order for me to know the status code I have to do res.status(404);next() then check if it's 404 in the middleware or last route - I use 404 as an example. I guess throwing errors it is

Comment: Not sure I get it, you have one route that matches the current URL, and if something goes wrong during a DB call in that route, you just call the next() callback, and it goes back and starts looking for other matching routes, and it shouldn't really find any, so it ends up in the last catch all route, and that's where you send the headers and the response.

Comment: For 404 only that would work - but how is the next matching route going to know if it's a 500, 401, 400 etc unless I tell it by doing res.status()?  So it's now either res.status(500);next() or just do res.send(500) and throw an error which seems cleaner. I guess I was hoping to catch things like res.send(500) like an error - perhaps some event fired from response on status code change or such

Comment: Well, it won't know that it's a 404, but that's not the point, the point is that the last route will send the 404 status as no other routes match, and you can trigger that action by leaving the current route with next() if something goes wrong and you would like to trigger a 404 instead. As for 500, that's a server error, and there are ways to handle that in node.

Comment: One thing to not on your example is that the wildcard route is not the best way to handle 404 - it forces router to be below static which is less efficient in tests I have seen.  A middleware function should be used instead imo